# C# MVC 4 razor Error al llenar por defecto las listas y al seleccionar un ítem de la primera lista

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, knockoutjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo un problema y es que no me está funcionado el llenado de datos en cascada:

Al hacer clic en nuevo debería cargar el texto por defecto **seleccione** en ambas listas.:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego selecciono el país y en departamento queda en blando y no carga solo los departamentos del país.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**#Vista:  ManTesting.cshtml**

```
 <div class="input-group">  
    <select id="COUNTRY_ID" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" name="COUNTRY_ID">
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.ListCountries)
             {
                 <text> <option value="@item.COUNTRY_ID">@item.NAME</option> </text>
             }
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">      
    <select id="DEPARTAMENT_ID" class="form-control" name="DEPARTAMENT_ID">
       @{
            foreach (var item in Model.ListDepartaments)
            {
                <text> <option value="@item.DEPARTAMENT_ID">@item.NAME</option></text> 
            }   
        }                                                                                        
    </select>
</div>
```

**#Controlador: ManTestingController**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ListDepartaments(int iCodigo)
        {
            BE.EDepartaments eDepartaments = new BE.EDepartaments();
            eDepartaments.COUNTRY_ID = iCodigo;
            var sRpta = _servicioDocumentacion.ListDepartaments(eDepartaments).Where(x => x.COUNTRY_ID == iCodigo).ToList();
            return Json(sRpta);
        }
```

**#Archivo .JS**

```
$("#COUNTRY_ID").bind("change", function () {
    debugger;

    var sendVal = { iCodigo: $("#COUNTRY_ID").val() };

    var sendData = { COUNTRY_ID: $("#COUNTRY_ID").val() };
    var lLista = postJson("/ManTesting/ListDepartaments", sendData);

    $("#DEPARTAMENT_ID").empty();

    for (var i in lLista) {
        debugger;
        if (lLista[i].NAME != null) {
            var opcion = "<option value=\"" + lLista[i].iCodigo + "\">" + lLista[i].NAME + "</option>";
            $("#DEPARTAMENT_ID").append(opcion);
        }
    }
    $("#DEPARTAMENT_ID").val(null);

});
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con el error.

Comment: no entiendo tu problema, qué es lo que no funciona, seleccionar una opción? o leerla desde el servidor?

Comment: @LPZadkiel son dos errores que tengo, el primero al cargar el formulario carga todos los valores de las dos listas y coloca el primer valor de la consulta en la lista lo cual debería colocar por defecto el texto seleccione.  El segundo error es cuando seleccionó el país no esta filtrando a solo los departamentos del país si no que me muestra en blanco.

Comment: me causa curiosidad que tengas `readonly` en el select, me parece que no se puede dejar un select como readonly, lo otro es que estas anidando las opciones con un text => `<text><option>...</option></text>` lo cual puede que te genere algún problema, elimina la eiqueta text deja solo la option a ver si te ayuda eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que los `select` tengas por defecto la opción "Seleccione" debes incluirla:

```
<div class="input-group">  
    <select id="COUNTRY_ID" class="form-control" name="COUNTRY_ID">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Seleccione</option>
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model.ListCountries)
            {
                 <option value="@item.COUNTRY_ID">@item.NAME</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <select id="DEPARTAMENT_ID" class="form-control" name="DEPARTAMENT_ID">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Seleccione</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Nota lo siguiente:

1. No es necesario poner `<text></text>` ya que Razor identifica los `<option>` como HTML.
2. Para los departamentos no cargues nada de inicio.
3. En ambos casos, debes poner el atributo `selected` al valor que quieras seleccionado por defecto.

Por otro lado, en tu controlador esperas un `iCodigo`, pero al final lo que estás mandando en tu JS es `COUNTRY_ID`; además, tu script es "síncrono" cuando AJAX es asíncrono. Debes cambiar el JS:

```
$("#COUNTRY_ID").bind("change", function () {
    debugger;

    var sendVal = { iCodigo: $("#COUNTRY_ID").val() };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/ManTesting/ListDepartaments",
        data: sendVal,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(responseFromServer){
            $("#DEPARTAMENT_ID").html('<option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Seleccione</option>');
            for (var i in responseFromServer) {
                if (responseFromServer[i].NAME != null) {
                    var opcion = "<option value=\"" + responseFromServer[i].iCodigo + "\">" + responseFromServer[i].NAME + "</option>";
                    $("#DEPARTAMENT_ID").append(opcion);
            }
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
});
```

De aquí nota lo siguiente:

1. Lo que ocurre con los datos no se escribe después de la instrucción AJAX. Es ello a lo que me refiero con lo de "sincronicidad": no sabemos cuánto pueda tardar el servidor en responder, y eso a JS no lo importa, no va a esperar y simplemente continuará con la siguiente línea.
2. Lo que quieras que ocurra después de que el servidor responda lo ubicas dentro de `success` (debería ser otro pero no lo recuerdo en este momeno, pero igual sirve). La respuesta del servidor lo utilizas como parámetro en la función que se ejecutará entonces.
3. Si el servidor responde con un error, puedes igualmente controlar lo que sucede, en este caso con `error` (como con `success`, no recuerdo el nombre "estándar" pero ese funciona).
4. Como yo lo escribí es una manera de hacerlo, pero existen muchas otras. Solo necesitas investigar un poco más respecto a AJAX.

Algo que no me convence es que utilices en la respuesta otra vez al `iCodigo`, ahí depende de qué es lo que mandas en la respuesta del servidor (que desde aquí no podemos determinar cuál sea el nombre correcto por utilizar).

Comment: gracias por tu aporte, seguiré investigando sobre Ajax.

Comment: @DAES si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como solución con la paloma debajo del número grande a la izquierda de la respuesta. Así ayudas a quien te ayudó y a cualquiera que pueda tener la misma duda que tú :) Happy hacking!

Comment: @  Kroneaux Schneider  me fue de mucha ayuda tus comentarios, muchas gracias. Marcado.